# Heat of reaction for a reversible reaction

Tags: kinetics

If we have a reversible reaction

$$\ce{A <=> B}$$

and we have the activation energies of the forward and reverse reaction can we use

$$E_a^\mathrm{rev} = E_a^\mathrm{fwd} - \Delta H$$

to find the heat of reaction? $E_a^\mathrm{rev}$ and $E_a^\mathrm{fwd}$ are the activation energies of the reverse and forward reactions, respectively; $\Delta H$ is the heat of reaction.

I have tried using this but am unsure as to the layout of the equation.

Comment: I don't see a question here. Maybe provide a specific example?

Comment: Suppose that the forward reaction is exothermic so that the product is $\Delta H$ below the reactant then $E_a^{fwd} +\Delta H= E_a^{rev}$. Draw a sketch.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Energy diagram]

As you can see from energy diagram of the reaction that 'Heat of Reaction' is

ΔH = Efwd- Erev.

So your expression is correct.

Comment: No your equation is not correct;  $\Delta H + E^{fwd} =E^{rev}$:  you should not assume that $\Delta H $ is negative.

Comment: It is ...in that case Efwd > Erev and ΔH > 0 .

Comment: still no; in your diagram $\Delta H $ has the same sign as the $E_a$.

Comment: oh.. I just took the diagram from net..overall ΔH < 0 as Erev> Efwd. But expression will always hold as Efwd, Erev will always > 0 . their magnitude decides whether ΔH is positive or not.